# Clean Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I did the translation from google so sorry for the grammar. I'm learning to program on my own and need some help. I want to clean the Entry widgets by clicking the button. The problem is that I don't know how to bind the command in class "class MainWindow".

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class InserFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__create_widget()
    def __create_widget(self):
        ttk.Label(self, text="Label1").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        keyword1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        keyword1.focus()
        keyword1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Label2").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        keyword2 = ttk.Entry(self)
        keyword2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Label3").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        keyword3 = ttk.Entry(self)
        keyword3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Label4").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        keyword4 = ttk.Entry(self)
        keyword4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        for widgets in self.winfo_children():
            widgets.grid(pady=7)

class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__create_widget()
    def __create_widget(self):
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button1").grid(row=0, column=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button2").grid(row=1, column=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button3").grid(row=2, column=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button4").grid(row=3, column=0)
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(pady=5)
        

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("400x400")
        self.title("Prova")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=4)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.__create_widgets()
  this--------->      ttk.Button(self, text="Clear").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="E")
    def __create_widgets(self):
        insert_frame = InserFrame()
        insert_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        insert_button = ButtonFrame()
        insert_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=5, pady=5)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a callback function to the `command` parameter when constructing a Button object.

```py
def button_callback():
   # Your clearing code here.
   ...

ttk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=button_callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a specific reason for you to create the frame elements by a function when you could create them in the `__init__` function directly. This way they could be directly assigned to instance variables. (see second section of my answer)

However, you can create a function for your `MainWindow` class which deletes the contents of the entries and assign this function to the `command` attribute of the `"Clear"` button:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, END


class InserFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # assign entries to instance variables to be accessed through frame instance
        self.k1, self.k2, self.k3, self.k4 = self.__create_widget()

    def __create_widget(self):
        ttk.Label(self, text="Label1").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        keyword1 = ttk.Entry(self)
        keyword1.focus()
        keyword1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Label2").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        keyword2 = ttk.Entry(self)
        keyword2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Label3").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        keyword3 = ttk.Entry(self)
        keyword3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Label4").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        keyword4 = ttk.Entry(self)
        keyword4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        for widgets in self.winfo_children():
            widgets.grid(pady=7)

        # return entries to access them
        return keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4


class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__create_widget()

    def __create_widget(self):
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button1").grid(row=0, column=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button2").grid(row=1, column=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button3").grid(row=2, column=0)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Button4").grid(row=3, column=0)
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(pady=5)


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("400x400")
        self.title("Prova")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=4)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        # assign created frame to instance variable
        self.insert_frame = self.__create_widgets()
        # give command argument to button with function to clear contents
        ttk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.clear_inputs).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="E")

    def __create_widgets(self):
        insert_frame = InserFrame()
        insert_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        insert_button = ButtonFrame()
        insert_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
        # retrun created frame to access it
        return insert_frame

    # function to clear the entries
    def clear_inputs(self):
        self.insert_frame.k1.delete(0, END)
        self.insert_frame.k2.delete(0, END)
        self.insert_frame.k3.delete(0, END)
        self.insert_frame.k4.delete(0, END)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.mainloop()
```

---

The following code is a little more clean by instanciating the widgets directly in the respective `__init__` of your custom frame classes. Further the frame classes are part of the main app.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, END


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("400x400")
        self.title("Prova")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=4)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        # directly creating widgets
        self.insert_frame = self.InsertFrame()
        self.insert_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.insert_button = self.ButtonFrame()
        self.insert_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
        # give command argument to button with function to clear contents
        ttk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.clear_inputs).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="E")

    class InsertFrame(ttk.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            # assign entries directly to instance variables instead of using the __create_widget function
            ttk.Label(self, text="Label1").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
            self.keyword1 = ttk.Entry(self)
            self.keyword1.focus()
            self.keyword1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
            ttk.Label(self, text="Label2").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
            self.keyword2 = ttk.Entry(self)
            self.keyword2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
            ttk.Label(self, text="Label3").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
            self.keyword3 = ttk.Entry(self)
            self.keyword3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
            ttk.Label(self, text="Label4").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
            self.keyword4 = ttk.Entry(self)
            self.keyword4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
            for widgets in self.winfo_children():
                widgets.grid(pady=7)

    class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            ttk.Button(self, text="Button1").grid(row=0, column=0)
            ttk.Button(self, text="Button2").grid(row=1, column=0)
            ttk.Button(self, text="Button3").grid(row=2, column=0)
            ttk.Button(self, text="Button4").grid(row=3, column=0)
            for widget in self.winfo_children():
                widget.grid(pady=5)

    # function to clear the entries
    def clear_inputs(self):
        self.insert_frame.keyword1.delete(0, END)
        self.insert_frame.keyword2.delete(0, END)
        self.insert_frame.keyword3.delete(0, END)
        self.insert_frame.keyword4.delete(0, END)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.mainloop()
```